# How to fix infinite loop with Asp.NET Identity Login using AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-identity

I am trying to set up Asp.NET Identity, and it seems to be set up correctly, but when I place the `[Authorize]` attribute on my `BaseController` class, I get an infinite loop redirecting to the Login page. Can anybody help me?

Note: Every Controller (including the AccountController) inherits from BaseController. Also, I am using .NET 4.5 and .NET MVC5.

Comment: Please provide the AccountController code plus the routeConfig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the `[AllowAnonymous]` [attribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx) in your login/register actions, so your code looks something like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class BaseController: Controller
{
    ...
}

public class AccountController: BaseController
{

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login() {
        ...
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl) {
        ...
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register() {
        ...
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Because you have added the `[Authorize]` attribute to your base controller, every action will require the user to be authenticated (including the Login action). However, in order for the users to be able to authenticate themselves, at least some actions like the Login action should be enabled for anonymous users. That's what you will achieve using the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have [AllowAnonymous] on the Method, and I just figured something out. For whatever reason, if I place the [Authorize] on the direct controller, it will work fine, but if I place it on the BaseController, it doesn't. Any idea why that would be happening?

Comment: That´s interesting... What happens if instead of setting the attribute in the `BaseController` you add it as a global filter? Also, are both controllers defined in the same assembly?(If in different assemblies, could you be referencing different MVC versions?)